# .net 5 gRPC Client can not connect to the service HOST on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, grpc

I am having the issue when running the API under IIS and getting the following error on the client

```
"Status(StatusCode=\"Cancelled\", Detail=\"No grpc-status found on response.\")"
```

Client code

```
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // This switch must be set before creating the GrpcChannel/HttpClient.
            AppContext.SetSwitch(
                "System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);

            var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            // Return `true` to allow certificates that are untrusted/invalid
            httpHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
                HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;

            var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001/",
                new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpHandler = httpHandler });
            var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);

            var reply = await client.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" });

            Console.WriteLine("Greeting: " + reply.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Server code

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddGrpc();
            services.AddGrpcReflection();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();

                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");
                });
            });

        }
```

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/protocols?view=aspnetcore-5.0

IIS do support HTTP/2 features to support gRPC after  Windows 10, OS Build 20300.1000

Update i found error in event view

```
Category: Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.ServerCallHandler
EventId: 6
SpanId: cff724fbe3176247
TraceId: 288c25acb18dd646ad3eaabfdd53175f
ParentId: 0000000000000000
RequestId: 8000000a-0004-fc00-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /greet.Greeter/SayHello

Error when executing service method 'SayHello'.

Exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: Trailers are not supported for this response. The server may not support gRPC.
   at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.GrpcProtocolHelpers.GetTrailersDestination(HttpResponse response)
   at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.HttpResponseExtensions.ConsolidateTrailers(HttpResponse httpResponse, HttpContextServerCallContext context)
   at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.HttpContextServerCallContext.EndCallCore()
   at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.HttpContextServerCallContext.EndCallAsync()
   at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.CallHandlers.ServerCallHandlerBase`3.HandleCallAsync(HttpContext httpContext
```

Comment: Before asking a broad question you need to find what actually caused of issue.  The Error message indicates you are not getting a Response from server which contains a status like 200 OK.  So a few things can be happening 1) TLS authentication is failing 2) Your connection is not completing 3) An exception is occurring after the connection completes.  I would check the Event Viewer on the server to see if any exception occurred that would help isolate issue. Also using a sniffer like wireshark of fiddler to determine if TLS passed, and the connection completed.

Comment: based on this https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9020 GitHub issue IIS can't host gRPC with HTTP/2.